# Is "acediast" too rarefied to be acceptable in literature?

Tags: word-usage, latin, archaicisms, greek

I'm editing a manuscript where the word "acediast" appears a perfect fit, but Merriam-Webster is the only online dictionary I can find that lists it as a word, with the exception of a few scrabble word finders. In fact, searching for the word in Google brings up only ~6k results, compared to ~800k for "acedia."

Question: Does there come a point where a word is considered too archaic to be used, even in literature, and are there any reliable sources that go into detail on this subject?

**Edit:** As some have pointed out, this question was based on the false premise that "acediast" was an archaic word, when instead it is a neologism that never caught on.

Comment: It is also listed in the Logolepsy n. - a person who is slothful or wickedly lax when it comes to spiritual or religious matters
 http://www.allhotelscalifornia.com/kokogiakcom/logolepsy/ow_a.html#acediast

Comment: I was going to look it up, but I was too bored and apathetic.

Comment: If the reader can be reasonably expected to know what acedia is, then it’s a fairly obvious formation that should work fine. Personally, I’d never heard of acedia before reading this question, so I’d be lost. Of course there comes a point where a word becomes too archaic (using _neb_ for ‘face’, _lich_ for ‘body’, _ened_ for ‘duck’, or _ymb_ for ‘around’ would clearly be too archaic, since none of those have been in regular use for over half a millennium); whether _acediast_ has reached that point is, I fear, rather a subjective question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think that is well said. I also think if the reader knows what acedia is, they should be able to parse what an acediast is. This appears to be a matter of gauging how many people will recognize "acedia."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Acedia* was used by Pope Francis in [*Evangelii Gaudium*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/apost_exhortations/documents/papa-francesco_esortazione-ap_20131124_evangelii-gaudium.pdf) in November 2013 (see para 81).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I must somehow have skipped that paragraph in my otherwise meticulous reading of the Pope’s writings!

Comment: Curiously, there's a recent reference in pop culture, as the *Casanova* comic book series is using it as its current subtitle: https://imagecomics.com/comics/series/casanova

Comment: @AndréParamés You’d think that the issue subtitled *Gula* would have a crossover cameo by Wolverine. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Merriam-Webster online entry for [*acediast*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acediast) suggests its first appearance wasn't until 1934. That in all the generations of English-speaking scholars and theologians coming to grips with Aquinas' discussion of the deep spiritual apathy inherent in *acedia* no one thought to coin a word for someone who suffers from this condition — or commits this sin — until 1934 should tell you that had they coined a term, it most likely wouldn't have been this one.

The inevitable conclusion is that the word is not archaic; it was simply a neologism that never caught on. There are also no *-ist/-ast* agent nouns formed from any of the other Seven Deadly Sins either: *superbia, avaritia, luxuria, invidia, gula, ira*. We also don't say **greedist* or **bipolarist*.

If the creation of the word itself was a lousy idea, it's likely an equally lousy idea to use it today.

[image]

*The inscription is from the Vulgate translation of the Book of Sirach (Ecclesiaticus) 6.26: "Bow down your shoulder, and bear her [personified Wisdom], and be not grieved with her bands." Engraving by 16th century Flemish engraver [Hieronymus Wierix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Wierix).*

Comment: I don’t understand the first paragraph. Why does the fact that no one coined _acediast_ until 1934 tell us that if they had, it wouldn’t have been _acediast_? That seems rather self-contradictory. And why would the creation of the word have been a lousy idea? _Acedia_ itself is taken via Latin from Greek, which also has _ἀκηδιαστής_, undoubtedly the source of _acediast_.

Comment: Lovely as your engraving is, it might be compassionate on our readers to give some translation for the Latin inscription at the bottom. I reckon you can improve on *“Lower your shoulder, and carry her memory, and let not her fetters **bum you out”*** if you try a little.  :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Lousy idea because 1) no similar coinages for any of the other seven deadlies  or other moral failings or mental conditions 2) apparently no necessity for such a coinage in a long history of (Western) Christian discourse since St. Thomas. 3) Almost no usage since coinage. I'm thrilled you are able to speak with such authority about a word you only met an hour ago.

Comment: @sumelic: Those influenced by the Greek rather than Latin Fathers spell it with a k: akedia. I even found a blog post that uses _akediast_: http://longish95.blogspot.de/2016/02/atticus-finch-donald-trump-and-dragons.html

Comment: The other six Latin deadly-sin names don't appear to be from Greek, which is a difference that would seem to be relevant since the  agent noun suffix that is the source of  English *-st* (-στής in Greek, although I think the sigma may technically not be part of the suffix, but of the preceding root) originally was used to form agent nouns from Greek verbs.

Comment: @KarlG: Good catch on the possibility of "k". I had forgotten about that spelling variation. The word is from Greek no matter how it is spelled: the spelling with *c* is just a more Latinized way of spelling it that follows the usual conventions used by the Romans to spell Greek loanwords in Latin.

Comment: @KarlG I don’t see how any of those three makes the coinage (or borrowing) a lousy idea. It may be a coinage that could, by and large, easily have been done without, but that doesn’t make it lousy, just somewhat unrequired.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The Edsel might have been a perfectly good car, but it was a total flop, you know, a lousy idea to bring it to market.

Comment: @tchrist: added the inscription.

Comment: @KarlG Thanks, I thought of *wisdom* but missed the capital for the personification.

Comment: @tchrist: Where did you get your charming translation?

Comment: @KarlG I pulled that holey translation wholly out of my own head of holes. :)  The clunkily translated  2nd-person subj/imp. for the deponent *acedior*  is why I grabbed for the "bum you out". I also read the Spanish translation of the Vulgate, which ran: *Somete tu hombro, y llévala, y no te sean pesadas sus prisiones.*  I liked that better than the English translations I found. "And let not her/its/his/their bonds/ties be too heavy for/to you = weigh you down." (dative of interest)

Comment: @KarlG Bringing the Edsel to market was a lousy idea because it cost Ford and its shareholders hundreds of millions of dollars and resulted in people losing their jobs. It had an actual negative impact on the lives of quite a lot of people. I don’t think borrowing a fairly obscure Greek word that anyone is free never to use has ever had any such averse effects. Overall, the coinage of _acediast_ in English has had a pretty negligible influence—positive or negative—on, well, just about anything at all, so I still don’t see what’s so terrible about it.

Comment: Let me try again. _Acedia_ isn't an obscure word per se but a highly specialized one still current among those who discuss Thomistic concepts and Roman Catholic moral theology and those who listen to them. When Pope Francis' first public statment _Evangelii Gaudium_ in Eng.trans. speaks of "pastoral acedia," the clergy, to whom this statement was primarily addressed will know what it means. Whether _acedia_ ultimately derives from the Greek was of no consequence to the Latin church. Within this fairly exclusive group someone comes up with a new word. It flops.

Comment: What is the source of your impressive illustration?

Comment: @Bread: added full attribution. The actual graphic I got from Wikipedia. Engravings of the Seven Deadly Sins as a matched set of sorts were immensely popular at the time.

Comment: @tchrist I'd have translated "don't let [...] bum you out" as *nil desperandum* ;o) (just because a lot of people, including I, have heard it and know what is meant..)

Answer (score 7):

There are writers who enjoy teasing readers by using words that they are pretty sure no-one will ever have seen before. If your aim is to communicate, rather than to tease, you would be well advised to use a word your intended readers will understand.

Comment: Anthony Burgess was a very fine writer and he used obscure words in every book he wrote. The purpose wasn't to tease but to show the narrator's erudition or ivory tower background, sometimes in a self-mocking way. In Clockwork Orange he made up new words. I would bet acediast found its way into one of his novels.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be based on a few false premises.

As KarlG points out, "acediast" doesn't seem to have ever been appreciably more common than it is presently, so it doesn't seem right to describe it as an "archaic word" (a description that implies that it was once more common than it is today). (The formation, as opposed to the specific word, does seem to have existed since Ancient Greek: Liddell and Scott's *Greek-English Lexicon* has an entry for *[ἀκηδιαστής](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)khdiasth%2Fs)* (*akēdiastēs*). There are also a few examples on the web of parallel forms in other languages, like *[acediaste](https://books.google.com/books?id=6QpGQVYWYL8C&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=acediaste&source=bl&ots=sAJ5j4qbAW&sig=ULswvCrGRJ5NRVG3HIC_ROrowVs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX7f7k97_ZAhUJWK0KHW7sAwAQ6AEISjAM#v=onepage&q=acediaste&f=false)* in French and *[acediasta](https://books.google.com/books?id=ucroCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT63&lpg=PT63&dq=acediasta&source=bl&ots=l4ulGwkBh6&sig=JuSqag1ifPO3VPL5_KeyqntUKTE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE7Zny97_ZAhUBDKwKHaLdB5AQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=acediasta&f=false)* in Portuguese, although I was only able to find examples of these in documents from recent years.)

Furthermore, whether a word is archaic or not is only one factor out of many that will affect whether a reader can understand it. The word "thou" is archaic, but almost any English speaker will understand what it means. The word "noetic" is not archaic, but many English speakers will not understand what it means.

Since there is no official specification of the English language, there is no authority that can prevent you from using difficult-to-understand, archaic, or even newly invented words in your writing. But depending on what the author's goals are, it might be wise to avoid doing that. That's a matter of writing advice, though, and so outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: Rare though it is, *apathist* is more used than *acediast*, less used than *acedia* —  which tells you something. Given that *acedious* / *accidious* are both rarer still, I suspect that few would recognize the base *acedia* for sloth or apathy.

Comment: @tchrist: Right, but I think it depends on the context: if some preceding paragraph in the manuscript is devoted to explaining the meaning of the word "acedia", then the reader may find it easy to guess from context what "acediast" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @sumelic: the problem is that acediast is to acedia as — what? — linguist to language? nudist to nude? certainly not gymnast to _gymnos_. Maybe enthusiast to enthusiasm, or cineast to cinema, only negative? As a neologism the word isn't especially transparent to its meaning.